# How to use Ambient Callback in android service?

Tags: android

I have found the answer that is working only on activity.Like

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AmbientModeSupport.AmbientCallbackProvider {}
```

but I want for android service. Also please suggest if any alternative is there.
I want to detect the ambient mode change in android wear OS.

Answer (score 0):

In CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine you have onAmbientModeChanged callback method.
If you dont want to use it, you can try to use BroadcastReceiver with Intent.ACTION_DREAMING_STARTED in it's filter.

Btw.
For activity ambient mode support you might want to use WearableActivity.